# No converter found capable of converting from type [org.bson.BsonTimestamp] to type [java.time.LocalDateTime]

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

If I got document with property timestamp Spring can't convert it to LocalDateTime. And this exception occurs. Can you help me how to implement custom converter which convert org.bson.BsonTimestamp to java.time.LocalDateTime. And how to import it in the project after that, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

create a class implements `Converter<ObjectNode, DBObject>, IObjectNode2ObjectConverter<DBObject>` and add this converter to mongos mapping-converter

```
<mongo:mapping-converter type-mapper-ref="customMongoTypeMapper">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="xx.DateToDateTimeConverter"/>
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```